# How Boolean values should be stored in Google Sheets for Google Data Studio data source?

Tags: google-sheets, boolean, datasource, looker-studio

We use Google Sheets as data source in Google Data Studio reports.
There is a need to export some flags and use them in reports.
But none of formats for boolean values I've tried do not work in Data Studio.
I've tried following options:

- TRUE/FALSE
- true/false
- 1/0
- yes/no

When I create new data source google sets default type as Text or Number. If I change type to Boolean manually then I get "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request" error message.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried this with identical results. However I found I could create a working Boolean field as a calculated field in the data source (my Sheets column called mybooleanfield and populated with =0=1 for FALSE and =1=1 for TRUE, just to make sure):

```
case when mybooleanfield='TRUE' then true else false end
```

This calculated field is a proper working Boolean in GDS.